# How to make a footer float with the page for some times and scroll after sometime

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I make a ribbon in the footer like this:

http://cfni.org/

That means float till some time and then scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of changing the position of the element from fixed to absolute.  In this example, I used jQuery to find when the bottom of the div was approaching and then reassign the position value for the ribbon div.

Here's the code:

```
//WINDOW LOAD
jQuery( window ).load(function() {

    jQuery( window ).on( "scroll", function(){

        // When Scroll gets to the bottom, keep the ribbon absolute instead of fixed.
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() > jQuery(document).height() - 50){  // This value determines the height when the position changes
            jQuery('.ribbon').css({"position":"absolute"});
        } else {
            jQuery('.ribbon').css({"position":"fixed"});
        }

        });

    });
```

And here's a link to working [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vvwwja)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have just replaced the position absolute to position unset to scroll it through the section.

Thank you so much again for giving me the solution.

Comment: Glad to help!  Cheers